# dsbulk to load in batches and improved throughput

Tags: cassandra-3.0, dsbulk

I am running dsbulk to load CSV into cassandra. I tried with a csv that has 2 million records and dsbulk took almost 1 hr 6 mins to load the file into DB.

```
    total | failed | rows/s |  p50ms |  p99ms | p999ms | batches
2,000,000 |      0 |    500 | 255.65 | 387.97 | 754.97 |    1.00
```

This is what I see from the console output. I am trying to increase the batches and also the no.of rows/sec. I have added maxConcurrentQueries and bufferSize but I still see dsbulk is starting with single batch and 500 rows/sec.

How can I improve the load performance for dsbulk?

Comment: What is the version of your source and target Cassandra clusters? What is the hardware specs of the machine where DSBulk is installed? Also, what is the output of running `./dsbulk --version` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using batching and other concurrent parameters with dsbulk but couldn't see any improvement. I have tried with datastax Cluster and Session api to create a session and used that session to execute batch statements.

```
cluster = cluster.builder().addContactPoints("0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0")
            .withCredentials("userName","pwd")
            .withSSL()
            .build();
    session = cluster.connect("keySpace");
BatchStatement batchStatement = new BatchStatement();
batchStatement.add(new SimpleStatement("String query with JSON Data"));
session.execute(batchStatement);
```

I have used ExecutorService with 10 threads and each thread inserting 1000 queries per batch.

I have tried with something like above and it worked fine for my use case. I was able to insert 2 million records in 15 mins. I am creating insert queries using JSON keyword and creating json from the resultSet. We can also use executeAsync in which case you application thread will finish in a minute or two but cassnadra cluster still took the same 15 mins to add all the records.

To read data from source sybase DB, I have used jdbcTemplate.queryForList which will list records as List> and each object in that list is map which can be converted to JSNO using JSON ObjectMapper writeValueAsString method.

Hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the full `dsbulk load` command that you used, source & target C* versions,  your hardware specs to triage this efficiently.

Please see comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599288/10410162).

> If you're doing a single threaded operation like loading from a single file (i.e. `-url /path/to/a/single_file.csv`) then there is not much we could do here to improve the throughput. One thing to try would be to allocate more memory to the DSBulk process itself via export `DSBULK_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx10G"` prior to running your load command. Try if that works out in your environment and make sure your target cluster is able to handle the increased load.

Comment: Hi Madhavan, my dsbulk command has basic parameters for connection and ssl. I am trying from a local machine with java Xmx as 4G and destination is a remote cluster. Not sure on the C* version. I am trying to upload from a single csv file. Just to understand there isn't any batching support for single file load..? trying with batchSize, concurrent requests and others. Don't really see a difference. Do you think there is a different way to do it where I can achieve the increased throughput

Comment: When you perform an `unload` operation, just specify a directory with `-url` so DSBulk would automatically split them into multiple files which you could point them during the `load` operation. Reg. batching, yes it has [default batching based on partition keys](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/batchOptions.html#_batch_mode_dsbulk_batch_mode_string). Based on your local machine's specs & target cluster's sizing, you could chew more with [this parameter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/engineOptions.html#dsbulkEngineOptionsMaxConcurrentQueries).